# Spark reliance on AsyncEventQueue for listeners

Tags: apache-spark

Does spark internally rely on the `AsyncEventQueue` for any of its logic? What I mean is, if I have a slow spark listener attached and if that causes events to be dropped. Will the dropping of events affect spark in any way?

```
AsyncEventQueue: Dropped 1282 events from shared since Thu Feb 24 14:20:47 UTC 2022
AsyncEventQueue: Dropped 6194 events from shared since Thu Feb 24 14:17:46 UTC 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope these are Warnings right. Listener reads these and render the spark-ui. So it won't impact the actual task, but may show incorrect details in spark-ui. This can be configured using below property, you can increase it to solve it.

```
spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity
```

Please note, increasing this value may result in the driver using more memory.

Comment: Yes warnings. Delays in events can cause issues. Check out `ExecutorMonitor` but i don't entirely understand it :)

Comment: "A monitor for executor activity, used by `ExecutorAllocationManager` to detect idle executors."

Comment: Never mind, i guess it's used when dynamic allocation is enabled. We don't use that

Comment: Right, this is used to estimate the workload for scaling. This may cause delayed scaling if  dynamic allocation is enabled but task should not be impacted. This queue is used for monitor purpose only.